# Is there any way to perform spatial filter on multiple layers together?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, filter, versioning

I have a scenario where a featureclass[Child Version] is queried for some overlapping features on [SDE.DEFAULT] Version using ISpatialFilter, After getting few result, these features are looped and again queried the same way on [Child version]. (exactly opposite).
This takes lot of time. I still hope that the compexity can be reduced somehow. Is there any ways that we can run spatial filter in some kind of combination, so as to increase performance.
I have tried Spatial Cache, but because extent is not known it takes lot of time to fill the cache.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

By design, all queries run on per feature class basis.
Further more, a spatial query is always slower than an attribute query.

Some ways of increasing a Spatial query are:

- Query on a smaller feature class
  (i.e. with fewer features)
- Have a an attribute that would narrow down the
  selectable features. use that for
  your where clause of your
  IspatialFilter
- Change the spatial
  Indexes and check if the performance
  is better. This is more of a trial
  and error method.